# How to trap error of wget process?

Tags: c#, wget

am doing application of downloading images using wget process in c#.
But while downloading images I am providing type of image i.e. .jpeg or .png. Through wget command.
If while downloading I am passing .jpeg and if .jpeg is not present, Then I want to trap error "file not found" through process class. But it is not happening.

My code is below:

```
class TrapProcessError
{
    private Process process = new Process();

    public TrapProcessError()
    {
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        string args= "-r -c -np --retry-connrefused --tries=0 "url containing image folder" -P C:\\Images --cut-dirs=2 -nH -A jpeg -o C:\\Images\\error.log";
        string filename= "path of wget\\wget.exe";
        process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.ErrorDataReceived += this.ProcessErrorData;
        process.OutputDataReceived += this.ProcessOutputData;
        process.Start();      
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();  
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }

    private void ProcessErrorData(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
       string message = e.Data;                    
        if (message.Contains("file not found"))
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Error :" +message);
           process.Close();              
        }     
    }

    private void ProcessOutputData(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string message = e.Data;
       Console.WriteLine("Output :" +message);  
     }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TrapProcessError trapProcessError= new TrapProcessError();
        trapProcessError.Start();
    }
}
```

In above code if jpeg is not present then in erroe.log coming "file not found". But through process class not trapping error i.e. in ProcessErrorData e.Data is always coming null. So how can I trap error is there any other way?

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wget (in versions above 1.12) does return a reliable [exitcode](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html).

> 0 No problems occurred.
>       1 Generic error code.
>       2 Parse error—for instance, when parsing command-line options, the ‘.wgetrc’ or ‘.netrc’...
>       3 File I/O error.
>       4 Network failure.
>       5 SSL verification failure.
>       6 Username/password authentication failure.
>       7 Protocol errors.
>       8 Server issued an error response.

Prior to 1.12 you're in trouble:

> In versions of Wget prior to 1.12, Wget’s exit status tended to be unhelpful and inconsistent. Recursive downloads would virtually always return 0 (success), regardless of any issues encountered, and non-recursive fetches only returned the status corresponding to the most recently-attempted download.

The exitcode of the process is handed back to the Process instance in the [ExitCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode(v=vs.100).aspx) property. You should leverage that and keep the (error) logging for convenience.

```
public void Start()
{
    string args= "-r -c -np --retry-connrefused --tries=0 "url containing image folder" -P C:\\Images --cut-dirs=2 -nH -A jpeg -o C:\\Images\\error.log";
    string filename= "path of wget\\wget.exe";
    process.StartInfo.FileName = filename;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.ErrorDataReceived += this.ProcessErrorData;
    process.OutputDataReceived += this.ProcessOutputData;
    process.Start();      
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();  
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();
    if (process.ExitCode > 0) 
    {
         // do what you need to do in case of an Error
         Console.WriteLine("Error occured:{0}", process.ExitCode);
    }
}
```

If you absolutely want to respond to the error messages that are logged (either to standardoutout or erroroutput), make sure you check the correct strings: If the log shows `ERROR 404: Not Found` then this `message.Contains("file not found")` will never be true. This is a reason I always tend to stay away from logfile parsing.

Do notice that processes are not required to write errormessage to the standard error stream. The errormessages can very well come in the standard output stream as well...

Comment: :I have tried this already.But when process is terminated coz of "fie not found"exception. ExitCode is coming zero only. That is not getting,why it is coming zero?

Comment: Yes it is sending  http 404 errorcode. Version of wget.exe is 1.11.4

Comment: Please upgrade wget to a version higher that 1.12

Comment: "HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2014-11-01 16:05:56 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Removing "path of file\\image.png" since it should be rejected."

Comment: I have searched for wget version 1.12.. But  have found this"wget 1.12, however this version does not currently compile for Windows"

Comment: by using wget 1.13.4 version. Images are not downloading. Only connecting to proxy:80

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't go for the 1.16 version?

Comment: I have checked for all versions. Images are not downloading

Comment: Maybe take that problem to [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/search?q=wget+proxy)